# Basic question regarding Python 2.7 classes, instances & variable scope

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I execute the following code:

```
class myClass:
    _a = 'a'

    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a;

    def set_a(self, new_a):
        self._a = new_a

    def print_a(self):
        print self._a


c = myClass('b')
print c._a
c.print_a

c.set_a('c')
print c._a
c.print_a
```

I expect the output to be:

```
b
b
c
c
```

But instead the result is:

```
b
c
```

Why is that so? The method print_a doesn't even seem to be able to find self._a.

Comment: You're not *calling* `print_a`…

Answer (score 2):

`c.print_a` is not executing anything. To run the function `c.print_a`, you should *call* it: `c.print_a()`.

Why is it even legal to use a function like that tho?! Yes, you can 'mention' functions, other attributes and pretty much any other name, and this *normally* won't do anything (for example, it won't actually run the function):

```
class T:
    thing = 4

T  # does nothing
T.thing  # does nothing

import math

math  # does nothing
```

On the other hand, if the attribute is special, 'mentioning' it may invoke some behaviour:

```
>>> class T:
...     @property
...     def thing(self):
...         print("Hello!")
... 
>>> T()
<__main__.T object at 0x10c2cec50>
>>> _.thing
Hello!  # It doesn't look like something is being called, but it actually is!
```